# Ideas for plugging a hole in granite vanity

Tags: repair, vanity, granite, hole-repair

I got a nice piece of granite for cheap, and I am almost ready to mount it on the new vessel is actually smaller than the dimensions!

See below:

[image: picture of the leftover when placing it on top with equal space on the sides]
[image: No space in front, only on the rear]
[image: Whole hole view..]

Any suggestions? Ideally I want to find a sink that will fully cover the hole, but so far my searches on Amazon.ca (I am in Canada) don't look promising - they are mostly curved and apparently just like the one in  pictures, the dimensions mentioned are of the top part, not of the base! I am not sure if the largest one I found so far would cover it fully in the base...

Edit:To explain why top mount and undermount is not suitable: the vanity its supposed to mount on(unfinished, unpainted yet):
[image]

Comment: You are trying to put a square peg in an ovel hole. Look for oval bathroom sinks.

Comment: I don't want under counter sink,  I want one that goes on top...

Comment: Oval above are available. Have you tried places other than Amazon?

Comment: This is an example. Look for drop in or dual mount, or top mount. https://www.amazon.com/Sinkology-SB203-18N-Edison-Bathroom-Hammered/dp/B00Z6S4X0E/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1550979881&sr=8-3&keywords=oval+bath+sink

Comment: They are? Not really no - how would I even go about perfectly matching that hole with oval one? The hole size is approximately 47.5cm/18.7" width (left to right) and 36.5cm depth (14.3")

Comment: Also second reason I prefer over the counter, is to save space beneath the counter in the vanity - I have it full of drawers (like I said a DIY vanity, with thought of the sink being on top...

Comment: The one I linked is a dual, meaning it can mount from above or below. You need to look for an oval top mount sink of the 18.7" size or as close to that as you can get. Then weed out the ones that won't fit the depth. Or, search for an oval top mount 19" x 14" and see what comes the closest to it. As for plugging the faucet holes, when you buy your faucet, you can get ones with a 3 hole setup or a plte to cover 2 of the 3 holes, or use a stainess steel hole black that you press it, put some caulk around the hole, and pop them in.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/SimplyCopper-Copper-Motif-Rolled-Vessel/dp/B002LCKUSC/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1550980468&sr=8-3&keywords=oval+bath+sink+19"

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Houzer-CHT-1800-1-Topmount-Stainless-Lavatory/dp/B001N0NTW2/ref=sr_1_12_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1550980468&sr=8-12-spons&keywords=oval+bath+sink+19"&psc=1

Comment: Thanks @JeffCates, I just looked into it, I now understand what is top mount and undermount - I edited the question (in the bottom) and added the picture of the vanity, to better illustrate WHY top mount is not a suitable solution, unfortunately  - the drawers extend ALL the way to the top, I am going to use all the space... take a look please.

Comment: So, then the real answer is you need a vessel mount. :) Look for an oval one as well, but this means it could be rather high for washing for shorter people. You can find a vessel mount making sure the bottom of the vessel is large enough to fit snug in the hole or on top to cover. You wil have plumbing, specifically drain, tht will need to go down through the drawer area. Here is an example: https://www.amazon.com/Enbol-GS-L2112-Tempered-Bathroom-Artistic/dp/B071WL8NL4/ref=sr_1_6_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1550981353&sr=8-6-spons&keywords=oval+vessel+sink+19"+bottom&psc=1

Comment: hehe, your taste is starkly different than mine @JeffCates! :) Do you think something like that can be snugly fit into the hole, **without** interfering with the drawer/drawer space? I am thinking of something along the lines of https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B00KGI4KH0/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza - but look at the dimensions page, it seems to suggest the bottom is actually only 10 inch wide! If true, So far I have not found a vessel sink that could possibly fit that hole fully.. not yet. And I am looking for something like that shiny white :)

Comment: I used those as examples, showing the first that shows up upon searching. I'm not a vessel person...yet. :) But it may take time to search for one to fit. Other options are maybe visiting a home center like Home Depot and seeing what they stock, take measurements and then do your search online.

Comment: Yeah that I know.. I will look tomorrow at Home Depot and the likes. Is there no way to at least slightly close that hole while keeping it aesthetically pleasing look?

Comment: I suppose if you could find a shop that throws out their granite scraps, like if they cut a hole in a counter top, they sometimes toss the cut piece...find one close to the size,, bigger and you can grind it to fit, then use silicone to attach the "fill" piece to the counter top, and use a few boards on the bottom to support the fill piece and the weight of the vessel including water. Instead of boards, you could use metal brackets screwed into the granite from below.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like this will be my last resort idea if all else fails... Its frustrating, I am looking online: https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/p.21-12-inch-w-x-16-34-inch-d-rectangular-vessel-sink-in-white.1000853268.html and they dont mention the size of the base either! I guess nobody thought of them being used to cover a hole like that :)

Comment: Ok, I did some further research now, I **think** I found stuff that should fit the hole: https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B01DGOTJR6?tag=amz-mkt-chr-ca-20&ascsubtag=1ba00-01000-org00-win10-other-nomod-ca000-pcomp-feature-pcomp-wm-8&ref=aa_pcomp or https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/p.2875-inch-x-625-inch-x-1975-inch-free-form-ceramic-bathroom-sink.1000693554.html or https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/p.25-inch-w-x-15-inch-d-rectangular-vessel-sink-in-white.1000853280.html - do you think those would cover the specified hole?

Comment: two ideas: ..... (1) get a square piece of granite that is big enough to cover the hole and put it under the sink .......(2) take the countertop to a granite shop and have them make the hole round, then set a round glass sink into the hole .... you would have to find a sink that is fairly large in diameter ..... https://www.amazon.com/Kraus-GV-399-19mm-Ladon-Vessel-Bathroom/dp/B00HI0EMWW

Answer (score 1):

Find a sink that you like with a slightly larger dimension and cut the granite to fit. With the right tools it's very easy and obviously you need to be careful. The only expensive item you need is a grinder. The others are a big sponge, bucket, diamond grinder wheel and water. It's a bit messy so I'd do it outside.

1 get your sink.

2 confirm that it is suitable.

3 measure and mark by scratching in the surface of the granite

4 on a flat surface shimed up for blade clearance, grinder in hand and sponge in the other. Wet soak the sponge and use it to keep the blade wet as you grind. (if you get help a hose will work)

Cut in from the opening to the line all around then cut on the line to knock off the pieces.

[image]

5 check for fit, trim if necessary and clean up.

I've done this before and it took about 20 minutes to do the actual cutting. I'm sure you can find videos online.

Comment: Hi Joe! I really appreciate the detailed post and effort made, but have you seen my edit as of 20 minutes ago at the bottom, showing the vanity? It has drawers, I cant do top mount or undermount, it has to be a vessel mount. Unless I misunderstand, and your rectangular suggested cuts are for vessel mount somehow?

Comment: Oh crap, I somehow missed the vessel part and didn't see the picture of the vanity. The shape doesn't matter, you can trim a little or a lot. if you get a vessel mount that is a close fit you can use this method but you would have to be very careful to get a clean line with a slight bevel. A nice caulk job would hide any imperfections and support the sink. Also I've been on jobs where pros come in and do the service for the customer. An experienced guy can make it look like a factory cut.

Comment: Some vessel sinks are sort of flat on the bottom around the edge. That way you wouldn't have to be so careful with the cut.

Comment: I dont quite visualize what you mean... at this point I am going to first try and find a larger vessel that would fully cover the hole, unless you could point me to an example of your meaning? The hole size is approximately 47.5cm/18.7" width (left to right) and 36.5cm depth (14.3").

Answer (score 1):

You may be trying to solve an X-Y type problem. Have you tried going to a granite shop and pricing a suitable sized slab of granite top that does not have a hole? You may find that the high prices charged for some special sink that can cover the hole is reasonably offset by the cost of a more reasonably priced sink.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for a shop sink in my lab and came up with a odd solution, I used the sink I had but used spacers to raise it about an inch above the counter top, then I cut a 2 part plastic adapter fitting that made a sloped connection between the two. about a 30 degree slope connecting the sink to the counter. I used plastic because that is what I could shape the easiest, but you may be able to use wood, metal, granite, or even putty. Scrap granite from trimming the countertop was my second choice. Failing that you might have to go with a large raised vessel sink.